# Casper slashes nodes with poor network connection?

Tags: casper

Moving from PoW to PoS sounds reasonable as it's more environmentally friendly and costs less to compensate miners.

However, I heard Casper will slash uncles to disincentives them from forming a fork. There are some undesired generated uncles right now because of network delay/slow propagation of block creation. Would those miners who created an uncle because of those reasons be punished as well?

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to differentiate between offline nodes and stopped nodes.

Having a bad internet connection and being offline looks the same.